# Creating a Discord Bot: ReferenceError: message is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have been working on creating a private Discord Bot and I've gotten pretty far with it as of now.

There's just 1 issue so far and I fear more in the future.

I am trying to implement an economy system (money system) going off of a video tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aw4b2VN1KW8) and I am coming across the same error.

I have an idea as to what the issue is, but I am unsure of what to do to fix it and how. Below, is my existing `index.js` code as of now (5/17/20). I'm also using Visual studio code.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const fs = require('fs');


let userData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./Storage/userData.json', 'utf8'));

if (!userData[message.author.id + message.guild.id]) userData[message.author.id + message.guild.id] = {}
if (!userData[message.author.id + message.guild.id].money) userData[message.author.id + message.guild.id].money = 500;

fs.writeFile('Storage/userData.json', JSON.stringify(userData), (err) => {
    if (err) console.error(err);
})

const token = 'my token';

const PREFIX = '+';

bot.on('ready', () =>{
   console.log('This bot is now online.');
   bot.user.setActivity('Mixing drinks');
})

bot.on('message', message=>{

    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

    switch(args[0]){
        case 'badtouch':
            message.channel.send('*pfffft* a bad touch...')
            break;  
        case 'website':
            message.channel.send('https://va11halla.fandom.com/wiki/VA-11_HALL-A_Wikia')
            break;
        case 'info':
            if(args[1] === 'description'){
                message.channel.send('Stuck here behind this screen in the "lovely" Glitch City, I mix drinks and change lives. Just be sure you have enough money to pay for drinks...');
            }else{
                message.channel.send('That is not a valid command')
            }
            break;
        case 'clear':
            if(!args[1]) return message.reply('There is an error')
            message.channel.bulkDelete(args[1]);
            break;
        case 'random':
            message.channel.send('I wonder if I left enough food at home for Fore... For fore, For four?')
            break;  
        case 'shareabeer':
            message.reply('Cheers. :beers:');
            break;
        case 'commands':
            const attachment = new MessageAttachment('./command list.txt')
            message.author.send(message.author, attachment);
            break;
        case 'aboutme':
            message.reply('My name is Jill, and __NO__, you cannot know my full name. I am alergic to shrimp, I do not mind spicy foods, however I do not really prefer it. A little after graduation and other *events*, I decided to become a bartender.')
            break;
        case 'kira':
            message.channel.send('MIKI!')
            break;
        case 'jules':
             message.reply('Call me Jules and I will make sure every time you sit, you will hear the *cling* of the shaker.')
             break;

    }
})

bot.login(token);
```

Below, is what I added to my `index.js` code and started receiving this error:

```
ReferenceError: message is not defined. if (!userData[message.author.id + message.guild.id]) userData[message.author.id + message.guild.id] = {}

ReferenceError: message is not defined
    at Object.< anonymous >
```

My bot before I added this small section to it worked just fine, but attempting to start it up receives the same `ReferreceError` :

```
let userData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./Storage/userData.json', 'utf8'));

if (!userData[message.author.id + message.guild.id]) userData[message.author.id + message.guild.id] = {}
if (!userData[message.author.id + message.guild.id].money) userData[message.author.id + message.guild.id].money = 500;

fs.writeFile('Storage/userData.json', JSON.stringify(userData), (err) => {
    if (err) console.error(err);
})
```

If I am not mistaken, I must define `message`, but how and where do I do that?

And if so, can an example be provided?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    bot.on('message', message=>{
```

this line represents an event listener with a callback function.
when your bot receives a message event, it handles this with a callback you defined by this anonymous function

```
    message => {
    }
```

this could be rewritten as

```
function handler(message){
   /// your logic
}
```

so inside this function, you have message as an input parameter. You use this variable to send and parse messages.

you need to do all of your work regarding messages inside that callback function where message is defined.

so put

```
if (!userData[message.author.id + message.guild.id]) userData[message.author.id + message.guild.id] = {}
if (!userData[message.author.id + message.guild.id].money) userData[message.author.id + message.guild.id].money = 500;
```

inside the function
    message => { }

and that should fix the ReferenceErrors